# How to interpret such value of the time column in /proc/self/mountstats - does it indicate a performance issue?

Tags: linux

I have some bladefs volume and I just checked `/proc/self/mountstats` where I see statistics per operations:

```
...
    opts:   rw,vers=3,rsize=131072,wsize=131072,namlen=255,acregmin=1800,acregmax=1800,acdirmin=1800,acdirmax=1800,hard,nolock,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=10.0.2.100,mountvers=3,mountport=903,mountproto=tcp,local_lock=all
    age:    18129
    caps:   caps=0x3fc7,wtmult=512,dtsize=32768,bsize=0,namlen=255
    sec:    flavor=1,pseudoflavor=1
    events: 18840 116049 23 5808 22138 21048 146984 13896 287 2181 0 7560 31380 0 9565 5106 0 6471 0 0 13896 0 0 0 0 0 0 
    bytes:  339548407 48622919 0 0 311167118 48622919 76846 13896 
    RPC iostats version: 1.0  p/v: 100003/3 (nfs)
    xprt:   tcp 875 1 7 0 0 85765 85764 1 206637 0 37 1776 35298
    per-op statistics
            NULL: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
         GETATTR: 18840 18840 0 2336164 2110080 92 8027 8817
         SETATTR: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
          LOOKUP: 21391 21392 0 3877744 4562876 118 103403 105518
          ACCESS: 20183 20188 0 2584304 2421960 72 10122 10850
        READLINK: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
            READ: 3425 3425 0 465848 311606600 340 97323 97924
           WRITE: 2422 2422 0 48975488 387520 763 200645 201522
          CREATE: 2616 2616 0 447392 701088 21 870 1088
           MKDIR: 858 858 0 188760 229944 8 573 705
         SYMLINK: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
           MKNOD: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
          REMOVE: 47 47 0 6440 6768 0 8 76
           RMDIR: 23 23 0 4876 3312 0 3 5
          RENAME: 23 23 0 7176 5980 0 5 6
            LINK: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
         READDIR: 160 160 0 23040 4987464 0 16139 16142
     READDIRPLUS: 15703 15703 0 2324044 8493604 43 1041634 1041907
          FSSTAT: 1 1 0 124 168 0 0 0
          FSINFO: 2 2 0 248 328 0 0 0
        PATHCONF: 1 1 0 124 140 0 0 0
          COMMIT: 68 68 0 9248 10336 2 272 275...
```

about my bladefs. I am interested in READ operation statistics. As I know the last column (97924) means:

> 8. execute:         How long ops of this type take to execute (from
>                      rpc_init_task to rpc_exit_task) (microsecond)

How to interpret this? Is it the average time of each read operation regardless of the block size? I have very strong suspicion that I have problems with NFS: am I right? The value of `0.1 sec` looks bad for me, but I am not sure how exactly to interpret this time: average, some sum...?

Comment: I [think it's the sum](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/sunrpc/stats.c#L179). Printing is from [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/sunrpc/stats.c#L239) and [entries here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/sunrpc/stats.c#L274).

Comment: Aha, I see `/* Add two ktime_t variables. res = lhs + rhs: */
#define ktime_add(lhs, rhs) ((lhs) + (rhs))`. It seems you are right. So this counter is not enough to claim that there is an issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the kernel source, the statistics are printed from [net/sunrpc/stats.c  rpc_clnt_show_stats()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/sunrpc/stats.c#L264) and the 8th column of `per-op statistics` statistics seems to printed from [_print_rpc_iostats](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/sunrpc/stats.c#L239), it's printing `struct rpc_iostats` member `om_execute`. (The newest kernel has 9 columns with errors on the last column.)

That member [looks to be](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/rpc_iostats) only referenced/actually changed in [rpc_count_iostats_metrics](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/sunrpc/stats.c#L179) with:

```
execute = ktime_sub(now, task->tk_start);
op_metrics->om_execute = ktime_add(op_metrics->om_execute, execute);
```

Assuming `ktime_add` [does](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/ktime.h#L48) what it says, the value of `om_execute` only increases. So the 8th column of mountstats would be the sum of the time of operations of this type.